# Docker NodeJS Puppeteer@2.0.0 - How do fix Failed to launch chrome! issue

Tags: node.js, docker, chromium, puppeteer, alpine-linux

**Without setting PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true and CHROMIUM_PATH /usr/bin/chromium-browser**
**Without chromium package**

> Error for printPdf()
>   Error: Failed to launch chrome! spawn /usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-706915/chrome-linux/chrome ENOENT

---

**With setting PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true and CHROMIUM_PATH /usr/bin/chromium-browser**
**With chromium package**

> Error is missing photos sometimes[image]

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN chmod -R 444 /etc/apk/
RUN echo "ipv6" >> /etc/modules

RUN set -x \
    && apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
RUN apk add -f

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true
ENV CHROMIUM_PATH /usr/bin/chromium-browser

# Installs latest Chromium package.
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    chromium \ ### with this, it is okay
    nss \
    freetype \
    freetype-dev \
    harfbuzz \
    ca-certificates \
    ttf-freefont \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    yarn

RUN yarn add puppeteer@2.0.0 adal-node@0.2.0 azure-keyvault@3.0.4 azure-sb@0.11.1 azure-storage@2.10.3 http@0.0.0

COPY package*.json ./

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

Below is my puppeteer.js:

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser', // if without using chromium package: executablePath: process.env.CHROMIUM_PATH,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--enable-font-antialiasing', '--font-render-hinting=medium'],
    timeout: LOAD_TIMEOUT,
    headless: true
});
```

Reference: [GoogleChrome/puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the `headless` value to `false`

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true
});
```

Comment: why headless false ?