# Chrome fails to load shared libraries: libX11.so.6

Tags: google-chrome, .net-core, dockerfile, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

We have a Docker file that worked as late as 22 December 2020, but all of a sudden it crashes in runtime if we build the same Docker file again and the exception is:

```
PuppeteerSharp.ProcessException: Failed to launch Base! /app/.local-chromium/Linux-706915/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is the relevant part of the docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

#Excluded since it is not relevant

#####################
#PUPPETEER RECIPE
#####################
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && curl -sSL https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    google-chrome-beta \
    fontconfig \
    fonts-ipafont-gothic \
    fonts-wqy-zenhei \
    fonts-thai-tlwg \
    fonts-kacst \
    fonts-symbola \
    fonts-noto \
    fonts-freefont-ttf \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl gnupg \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#####################
#END PUPPETEER RECIPE
#####################

ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH "/usr/bin/google-chrome-beta"

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Our.File.dll"]
```

I'm by no means experienced Docker/Linux developer, but we have this is production working well for almost a year now.

When searching for the problem we have found many things to try. Among the things I have tried and all failed are these:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64293743/6743788
2. Manually adding dependencies (tried it before and after our RUN apt-get above):

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
          gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
          libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
          libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
          libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \
          ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

This suggestion was first found here: https://medium.com/@ssmak/how-to-fix-puppetteer-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libx11-xcb-so-1-c1918b75acc3
When watching the build output, we noticed that most of the dependencies already existed with the latest version.

3. Tried to specify an older version of Chrome (we have tried with a couple of different versions):

```
#####################
#PUPPETEER RECIPE
#####################
ARG CHROME_VERSION="81.0.4044.138-1"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -f install && apt-get -y install wget gnupg2 apt-utils
RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chrome.deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y /tmp/chrome.deb --no-install-recommends --allow-downgrades fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf \
&& rm /tmp/chrome.deb

#####################
#END PUPPETEER RECIPE
#####################
```

4. Tried 3 plus 2 together
5. Also tried to add `libgbm-dev` to the dependency list because we found that somewhere.

I have tried to verify that the files exist in the docker file by running these commands (and their output) in the container:

```
root@5c47052da1d8:/app# dpkg-query -L libx11-6
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libx11-6
/usr/share/doc/libx11-6/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libx11-6/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libx11-6/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libx11-6/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/libx11-6/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libx11-6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
root@5c47052da1d8:/app# ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Sep 11 16:16 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 -> libX11.so.6.3.0
root@5c47052da1d8:/app# ldd libX11.so.6
ldd: ./libX11.so.6: No such file or directory
root@5c47052da1d8:/app# ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc432b3000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fe8b0ad2000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe8b0acd000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe8b090c000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fe8b0708000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fe8b0502000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe8b0c45000)
        libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fe8b04e8000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe8b04dc000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe8b04bb000)
```

I have read https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

Any help would be greatly appreciated, because I've got no clue how to solve this or what to try next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the problem and document it here if it happens to someone else. It turned out to be how Visual Studio does the building now.

If I right-click and build the Dockerfile in Visual Studio the result will be correct just as my investigations above showed. The problem is that when I wanted to test the image, I run it by F5 (or Ctrl+F5) in VS and in that case Visual Studio does not build my Dockerfile by default. I thought that it used my recently build result (cached), but it actually uses another cached result. For performance reason it builds the project locally and take that result and adds it to the aspnet:3.1-buster-slim image, which means that my custom dependencies are not added.

This behaviour can be controlled by setting  in the project file. The default value of if is Fast which does not use my Dockerfile, but setting it to Regular does, on the cost of slower start up.
Documentation of this and other settings can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019